# jPlayer event not working on flash solution

Tags: jquery, jplayer

I am using the jPlayer plugin as an audio player, but it seems that certain events like `loadeddata` does not work when I set this property: `solutions: "flash, html"`.

Here is my code below:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
            ready: function(event) {
                $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                    mp3: "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/TSP-01-Cro_magnon_man.mp3",
                    oga: "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/TSP-01-Cro_magnon_man.ogg"
                });
            },
            swfPath: "http://jplayer.org/latest/dist/jplayer",
            solution:"flash,html",
            supplied: "mp3, oga"
        });

$("#jquery_jplayer_1").bind($.jPlayer.event.loadeddata,function(event){
   $(this).jPlayer("play") });
});
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages (like in your console)?

Comment: No @RalphWiggum . I have added some animation / show / hide content under `loadeddata` and animation / show / hide not working and when i go with `ready` event it working but i need loadeddata .

Comment: @Megi did you find a solution for this problem?